# Javascript Can't Update Gradient

Tags: javascript, css, css-gradients

I can't seem to update the linear gradient I've applied to my navbar. It works fine when I
set it in my css file like so

```
.navbar-light {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 204, 153, 1), 75%, rgba(255, 204, 153, 0));
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work through Javascript even though I can set other attributes within the same function like so

```
function myFunc() {
    var nav = document.getElementById("myNavbar");
    nav.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(rgba(255, 204, 153, 1), 90%, rgba(255, 204, 153, 0));"
    console.log(nav.style.backgroundImage);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think there shouldn't be a semi-column at the end here: `rgba(255, 204, 153, 0));"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eh those semicolons :P

```js
(function myFunc() {
    var nav = document.getElementById("myNavbar");
    nav.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(rgba(255, 204, 153, 1), 90%, rgba(255, 204, 153, 0))" // look on your code here
})()
```

```css
.navbar-light {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 204, 153, 1), 75%, rgba(255, 204, 153, 0));
}

div.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box navbar-light"> 1 </div>

<div id="myNavbar" class="box"/> 2 </div>
```